# Firebase - upload additional files to already deployed app

Tags: firebase

I have already deployed an app in firebase. Now I have to upload additional files to my app. How can I add additional files to already deployed app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's quiet simple!

Add all the files that you want to upload to your app in the directory that you have fixed for firebase. Eg: public

Then in command prompt, type `firebase deploy --only hosting`.

Now your app is ready with additional file!!